# Using VS Code, when creating a theme, how do I change the semantic styling of an attribute on a specific HTML element type only?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, themes

I am creating a theme for VS Code and I'm currently setting the styling for all of the semantic token colors. What I'm trying to do is create a scope for deprecated tags and attributes. For the most part, I have this working using the following in my color-theme.json file.

```
{
  "name": "PrismaPixel Studios - Dark Theme",
  "type": "dark",
  "colors": {},
  "tokenColors": [
    {
      "name": "deprecated",
      "scope": [
        "invalid.deprecated.entity.other.attribute-name.html",
        "invalid.deprecated.html",
        "invalid.illegal.no-longer-supported.html",
      ],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#ff9c8f",
        "fontStyle": "strikethrough",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue that I'm running in to is that there are certain attributes that are deprecated only on certain elements. For example, the `charset` attribute is deprecated on the `<script>`, `<link>` and `<a>` tags but it's still allowed on `<meta>` tags. If I add `"meta.attribute.charset.html"` to list of scopes under deprecated it will also apply the strikethrough and red to the meta tag in the head.

The Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes tool gives this information for the charset attribute:

[image: charset token inspector]

How do I go about targeting a specific attribute such as `charset` only on specific elements such as `<meta>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [descendant selectors](https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors#descendant_selectors). From the TextMate v1 docs:

> As with CSS, it is possible to use the context of an element in the scope selector. [...] In the scope selector we specify element names as a space separated list to indicate that each element should be present in the scope (and in the same order).

So for example, to get charset attributes inside `<meta>` tags:

```
meta.tag.metadata.meta.void.html meta.attribute.charset.html entity.other.attribute-name.html
```